# Welcome tour/showcase library for WPF/Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I'm looking for a way to showcase new features in a WinForms/WPF mixed application.

I found [this](https://github.com/sorrycc/awesome-javascript#tours-and-guides) links to such libraries only for web apps.

Ultimately I want to achieve something like [this](http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/), But I'll even settle for a static picture with opacity and arrows to the new features.

Any idea on how I can achieve such a thing in WPF/Winforms?

Comment: This might be possible in WPF because of the declarative nature of the UI and the good support for transparent layering you can do, however, WinForms will be a challenge.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth the features I need to showcase are in winforms, However I managed to create a semi-transparent popup in WPF that darkens the entire application area, but I'm struggling with highlighting the specific areas I want to showcase

Comment: I would assume you'd need to calculate the four rectangles needed to draw a box around a fully transparent box to "highlight" the relevant area. If you need to highlight multiple regions then you'd need to draw multiple partially transparent boxes.

Comment: Are you using third party frameworks like telerik or devexpress? Your ultimately idea for WinForms will be really hard. But starting with a static picture shouldn't be that problem.